# Function with convex polytopes as sub-levelsets

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

If a function has convex sub-levelsets then it is quasiconvex. What if it has sub-levelsets that are convex polytopes? Obviously, it is still quasiconvex but is there a name for this class of function and are they studied?